# Correct way of determining the range of validity when expanding (1+f(x))^n

Tags: convergence-divergence, binomial-theorem

Consider the following three ways to expand $\frac{1}{1+3x+2x^2}$ = $\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+2x)}$ = $\frac{2}{1+2x}$ $-$ $\frac{1}{1+x}$ using the standard binomial series expansion for $(1+x)^n$ valid for $|x|<1$:

(a) $(1+y)^{-1}$ where $y=3x+2x^2$ valid for $|y|<1$

(b) $(1+x)^{-1}$ * $(1+2x)^ {-1}$ valid for $|x|<1/2$

(c) $2(1+2x)^{-1}$ $-$ $(1+x)^{-1}$ valid for $|x|<1/2$

These methods all seem to give the correct power series as far as you want to go.

Now with (b) and (c) the correct range of validity, $-0.5<x<0.5$ drops out clearly.
However, for (a) the range of validity is $|y|<1$ which gives a different set of values for the range of validity for $x$.

What is the resolution? Abandon method (a)? Why doesn't it work?

In general, is the expansion for $(1+f(x))^n$ valid for $|f(x)|<1$?

Comment: when you write $\dfrac 1{1 + 3x + 2xx}$ to you mean $\dfrac 1{1 + 3x + 2x^2}$?  You can write $x^2$ by using `$x^2$`.  You can surround your expressions by dollar signs on each end, and when using exponents, use, e.g. `$(1 + y)^{-1}$` to get $(1+y)^{-1}$, i.e., use curly brackets when the exponent is more than one character.  Now, try taking these tips to try and format your question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Here's an admittedly rather long but very helpful tutorial on MathJax formatting to make the mathematics in your question easier for everyone (including you, most likely) to read: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you for helping me format my question better. I hope that it makes sense now.

Comment: I am interested in this question also. In particular, the more general question at the end. For example, If you can expand $(1+\arctan(x))^n$ for some n (maybe for all n?) then the range of convergence will be |$f(x)| < 1 \implies x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: This is a hard question to answer. The very very short and practical answer is: the partial fractions method is the "best" method for these "range of validity with Binomial expansion" questions.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: my answer is incomplete/ possibly wrong, so don't read too much into it at the moment. I think I've got a better answer coming along shortly...

"In general, is the expansion for $(1+f(x))^n$ valid for $|f(x)|<1$?"

Yes. See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Conditions_for_convergence

In particular, quoting the general Binomial series from the above link:

> \begin{align} (1 + x)^\alpha  &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \; {\alpha
> \choose k} \; x^k   \qquad\qquad\qquad (1) \\ &= 1 + \alpha x +
> \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!} x^2 + \cdots \end{align}
>
> Whether (1) converges depends on the values of the complex numbers $\alpha$
> and $x$. More precisely:
>
> If $|x| < 1$, the series converges (absolutely) for any complex number $\alpha$.

So to clarify, seeing as you probably only care about convergence in $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $\mathbb{C}$, if there is a domain $D = \{{s:|f(s)|< 1}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ then the (general) Binomial expansion of $(1+f(x))^n$ converges on D for *any* real number $n$. (Note: absolute convergence implies convergence).

If it's not clear what I'm getting at, think about it like this: The (Newton's) general Binomial expansion is just saying that, for some numbers, $(1) $ works. What I'm saying in the previous paragraph is, for any number $a \in D$, $f(a)$ is also just a number for which $(1)$ works.

For other cases e.g. when $|f(x)| = 1$, see the link above and just apply it to $\mathbb{R}$, which is fine because obviously $\mathbb{R} \subseteq\mathbb{C}$

Also, see the wikipedia link for proofs (e.g. proof of why the Binomial expansion works).

*Dislaimer: The rest of my answer is incomplete, and could probably be revised by someone more familiar with the ins and outs of conditional convergence / Riemann Series Theorem, of which I only have a baseline knowledge.*

Back to your examples (a), (b) and (c). Why do they have different radii of convergence?

Well, my guess would be that (b) and (c) tell you that  $|x| < \frac{1}{2} \implies $ the binomial expansion for those functions converge. But that does not mean they do not converge outside of $|x| < \frac{1}{2}$: it does not say it is valid for *only* $|x| < \frac{1}{2}$. Here, you've got two alternating series, so assuming they are [conditionally convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence) (are they?), then by the Riemann Series Theorem, a rearrangement of terms can result in *any* real number.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

I'm not sure about (b) because I'm not sure about multiplying two alternating series- it might also depend *how* you multiply the two brackets.

But for series (c) my guess would be that

$ \qquad 2(1+2x)^{-1} - (1+x)^{-1}
\\
 \quad =2(1-2x+4x^2 +...) - (1-x+x^2+...)$

and if you do not re-arrange terms, this indeed converges for *only*  $|x| < \frac{1}{2}$.

But if you rearranged and grouped the x-coefficients to get:

$ \qquad 2(1+2x)^{-1} - (1+x)^{-1}
\qquad= 2(1-2x+4x^2 +...) - (1-x+x^2+...)
\qquad= 1-3x + 7x^2 -15x^3+...$,

which is what I imagine the expansion of (a) is,

then maybe the radius of convergence really is different, and this is permitted by the Riemann Series Theorem. i.e. different re-arrangements of the series will give different values of x converging (and diverging).